# bash rest-api call authentication problem, I propaly use wrong syntax in my rest-api call but can't find the error

Tags: bash, rest

I wrote a powershell script for setting downtimes in our monitoring software "checkmk" and now I have to convert that so a bash script because we are switching from windows server to linux.

*user will be "XXX" password will be "YYY" and the hostname will be "ZZZ"*

For that I used the documentation from CheckMK:
[documentation for show sheduled downtimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEwbv.png)
[documentation for setting a downtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL1Aa.png)

and in the end it looks like that:

```
    <#
.Synopsis
   Downtime per Rest API bei Check MK Setzen
.DESCRIPTION
   Doku https://apt-omd-vip.ads.vhv.de/umbrella/check_mk/openapi/#operation/cmk.gui.plugins.openapi.endpoints.downtime.create_host_related_downtime
   30 min Downtime Setzen  = 1800 sekunden
.EXAMPLE
   Example of how to use this cmdlet
.EXAMPLE
   Another example of how to use this cmdlet
#>
function set-Downtime
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([int])]
    Param
    (
        $USERNAME="XXX",
        $PASSWORD="XXX",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $HOSTNAME,
        #Zeit soll die Downtime in Minuten angeben, wird dieseer Parameter leer gelassen wird Standdardmäßig 30min verwendet.
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Int]$TIME=30
    )

    Begin
    {
    }
    Process
    {
    

    #=============
    # Abfrage der DownTimes, sonst kein Connect möglich
    #=============

    $headers = @{
    ‘Accept’ = ‘application/json’
    ‘Authorization’ = “Bearer $USERNAME $PASSWORD”
    }

    $body = @{
             'host_name' = $HOSTNAME
              }   
 
    
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls11 -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 

    
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -uri “here was a URL” -Headers $headers -Body  $body 
 

   
    #write-host($rest_uri)
    

    #=============
    # DownTime
    #=============


    $headers = @{
    'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
    ‘Accept’ = ‘application/json’
    ‘Authorization’ = “Bearer $USERNAME $PASSWORD”
    }

    $datum_start = (get-date).AddHours(-2).ToString("u") 
    $datum_ende = (get-date).AddHours(-2).addminutes($TIME).ToString("u") ;
    $comment = "$TIME min Restart Downtime, $EXTRAINFO"

    $body =@{
            start_time = $datum_start;
            end_time =   $datum_ende;
            comment =  $comment;
            host_name = $HOSTNAME;
            downtime_type = 'host';
             }  | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
        
    
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -uri "here was a URL" -Headers $headers -Body $body
    
    
    }
    End
    {
    }
}
```

I apologize for the english-german mix in the script but in theory you shouldn't need my comments.

I reconstructed the command [from this bash to powershell help blog](https://virtuallysober.com/2019/03/12/converting-curl-to-powershell-for-rest-apis/)
Here is one time my bash script hole and after that I will only post the part I changed:

```
#!/bin/bash

##Variables

base_url='here was a URL'
request_url="$base_url/all"
post_url="$base_url/host"
user="XXX"
passwd="YYY"
hostname="ZZZ"
user_pass="$user:$passwd"

#header=["Accep"t = "application/json"
#"Authorisation" = "Bearer $user $passwd"]
#body1=["host_name" = "ZZZ"]


curl -u $user_pass -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' -d {'host_name: ZZZ'} 'here was an URL'
```

as I am still unexperienced in bash I tried my decleration of variables with the '' and "" quotes because I am still not sure when to use what (but thats not the question here)
Answer is following:

```
{"title": "You need to be authenticated to use the REST API.", "status": 401}
```

Next thing I tried was a header construct similar to my ps script:

```
header=( ["Accept"]="application/json" ["Authorization"]="Bearer XXX YYY")


curl --anyauth -X GET --header $header -d {'host_name: ZZZ'} 'here was an URL'
```

the answer this times was ***way longer** but in the end I got the same error message*:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "censored doc url">
<html>
<!-- FileName: index.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Head-->
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
  <title>McAfee Web Gateway - Notification</title>
  <script src="censored" type="text/vascript" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="censored" />
</head>
<!--/Head-->
<!--Body-->
<body onload="swOnLoad();">
  <table class='bodyTable'>
    <tr>
      <td class='bodyData' background='censored'>
<!--Logo-->
<table class='logoTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='logoData'>
      <a href='http://www.mcafee.com'>
        <img src='censored'>a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Logo-->
<!--Contents-->
<!-- FileName: authenticationrequired.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Title-->
<table class='titleTable' background='censored.jpg'>
  <tr>
    <td class='titleData'>
      Authentication Required
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Title-->

<!--Content-->
<table class="contentTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="contentData">
      You must be authenticated to access this URL.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   urlprotocol = "http";
   statuscode=407;

   if(statuscode==401 && urlprotocol == "ftp"){
      document.write("<form name=\"ftpform\" method=\"get\" action=\"\">");
      document.write("<table class=\"contentData\">");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\" colspan=2>Please enter youcredentials in the form below and click \"Access FTP\" button if your browser esn't present authentication prompt for FTP sites.</td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\">Username:</td><td><input te=\"text\" id=\"ftpUsername\" name=\"ftpUsername\" size=40 /></td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\">Password:</td><td><input te=\"password\" id=\"ftpPassword\" name=\"ftpPassword\" size=40 /></td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\" colspan=2 align=center><int type=\"button\" onclick=\"redirectToFTP();\" value=\"Access FTP\" /></td></t");
      document.write("</table>");
      document.write("</form>");
   }

   function redirectToFTP(){
      var username=escape(document.getElementById("ftpUsername").value);
      var password=escape(document.getElementById("ftpPassword").value);
      location.href = "ftp://"+username+":"+password+"@XXX:80/"
   }
</script>
<!--/Content-->

<!--Info-->
<table class="infoTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="infoData">
      <b>URL: </b><script type="censored");</script><br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Info-->

<!--/Contents-->
<!--Policy-->
<table class='policyTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyHeading'>
      <hr>
      Company Acceptable Use Policy
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyData'>
      This is an optional acceptable use disclaimer that appears on every pageYou may change the wording or remove this section entirely in index.html.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Policy-->
<!--Foot-->
<table class='footTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='helpDeskData' background='censored'>
      For assistance, please contact your system administrator.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='footData'>
      generated <span id="time">2022-08-09 14:58:22</span> by McAfee Web Gatew
      <br />
      curl/7.60.0<br />
Node: censored<br />
Client IP: censored<br />
User: <br />
User-Groups:  <br />
Authentication Method: <br />
Rule Set: Authentication with Kerberos and NTLM Fallback<br />
Rule: Perform Authentication<br />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Foot-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<!--/Body-->
</html>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "censored">
<html>
<!-- FileName: index.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Head-->
<head>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
  <title>McAfee Web Gateway - Notification</title>
  <script src="censored" type="text/vascript" ></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/default/styleeet.css" />
</head>
<!--/Head-->
<!--Body-->
<body onload="swOnLoad();">
  <table class='bodyTable'>
    <tr>
      <td class='bodyData' background='censored'>
<!--Logo-->
<table class='logoTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='logoData'>
      <a href='http://www.mcafee.com'>
        <img src='censored'>a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Logo-->
<!--Contents-->
<!-- FileName: authenticationrequired.html
     Language: [en]
-->
<!--Title-->
<table class='titleTable' background='/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/defaulimg/bg_navbar.jpg'>
  <tr>
    <td class='titleData'>
      Authentication Required
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Title-->

<!--Content-->
<table class="contentTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="contentData">
      You must be authenticated to access this URL.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   urlprotocol = "http";
   statuscode=407;

   if(statuscode==401 && urlprotocol == "ftp"){
      document.write("<form name=\"ftpform\" method=\"get\" action=\"\">");
      document.write("<table class=\"contentData\">");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\" colspan=2>Please enter youcredentials in the form below and click \"Access FTP\" button if your browser esn't present authentication prompt for FTP sites.</td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\">Username:</td><td><input te=\"text\" id=\"ftpUsername\" name=\"ftpUsername\" size=40 /></td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\">Password:</td><td><input te=\"password\" id=\"ftpPassword\" name=\"ftpPassword\" size=40 /></td></tr>");
      document.write("<tr><td class=\"contentData\" colspan=2 align=center><int type=\"button\" onclick=\"redirectToFTP();\" value=\"Access FTP\" /></td></t");
      document.write("</table>");
      document.write("</form>");
   }

   function redirectToFTP(){
      var username=escape(document.getElementById("ftpUsername").value);
      var password=escape(document.getElementById("ftpPassword").value);
      location.href = "ftp://"+username+":"+password+"@YYY:80/"
   }
</script>
<!--/Content-->

<!--Info-->
<table class="infoTable">
  <tr>
    <td class="infoData">
      <b>URL: </b><script type="text/javascript">break_line("http://setDownTim");</script><br />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Info-->

<!--/Contents-->
<!--Policy-->
<table class='policyTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyHeading'>
      <hr>
      Company Acceptable Use Policy
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='policyData'>
      This is an optional acceptable use disclaimer that appears on every pageYou may change the wording or remove this section entirely in index.html.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Policy-->
<!--Foot-->
<table class='footTable'>
  <tr>
    <td class='helpDeskData' background='/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/deflt/img/bg_navbar.jpg'>
      For assistance, please contact your system administrator.
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='footData'>
      generated <span id="time">2022-08-09 14:58:22</span> by McAfee Web Gatew
      <br />
      curl/7.60.0<br />
Node:censored<br />
Client IP: censored<br />
User: <br />
User-Groups:  <br />
Authentication Method: <br />
Rule Set: Authentication with Kerberos and NTLM Fallback<br />
Rule: Perform Authentication<br />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--/Foot-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
<!--/Body-->
</html>
{"title": "You need to be authenticated to use the REST API.", "status": 401}
```

---

I needed to cut that part because I was over the characterlimit for the post...

I think that my error is not that hard to solve but I dont know enough about bash to search for the right things so please get easy on me. I used bash the first time in june this year so try to keep the answers a bit simpler than to an usual bash user please, thank you in advance for your help and consideration.

Comment: Adding multiple headers to `curl` requires multiple `-H` arguments, have you tried: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer (TOKEN)" -d '{"host_name":  "ZZZ"}' (THE URL)`?

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, I didnt tried it until now, but sadly the reply stays the same...

Comment: Your bash call still needs to provide all the JSON fields that your Powershell script provides, I imagine.

Comment: yeah got the same thought today at breakfast, but at my first rest call in my ps script I didnt compress it o JSON and I am still trying to do the first off the two... I will try it but I am not shure that will to the thing...

Answer (score 1):

Like I guessed my problem was a minor one... only thing wrong was the ":" in my headers, just had to exchange them for "=".

Well got a new problem but I doubt that you guys can help me when I am not allowed to share more information about our server and applications.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

afer that message I did the same thing in the body like in my header but that didnt do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite of your script in `bash` using `curl`, because it'll be easier to discuss against an example rather than an abstract in comments.

This, at least to my eyes, does exactly what your Powershell script is doing.

```
#!/bin/bash

url="https://YOUR-URL"
username="XXX"
password="YYY"
hostname="ZZZ"

# first Invoke-RestMethod, which is a GET with JSON...

# -1 means "use TLS1 or newer"

# -XGET is required here to force it to be a request
# that uses GET with a body, since curl would default to POST
# if '-d' is specified

# -w "%{http_code}\n" means output the http code

# if you want to suppress all other output and only 
# get the http code output, specify these additional options:
# -o /dev/null -s

curl $url -1 -XGET \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $username $password" \
    -w "%{http_code}\n" \
    -d "{ \"host_name\": \"$hostname\" }"
   
# Downtime Invoke-RestMethod

minutes_diff=30
start_diff=120

# because in your original, you do (now - 2 hours) + $minutes_diff 
# so it's just now -(120 - $minutes_diff) minutes
end_diff=$(( 120 - $minutes_diff ))

# This was based on you using the .NET -u specifier which is
# intended for use with UTC DateTime objects

# I don't know if you actually want your timestamps derived
# from UTC time, which is what "-u" does for the date command

start_time=$(date -u -d "$start_diff minutes ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ")

end_time=$(date -u -d "$end_diff  minutes ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%SZ")

# you didn't have an EXTRAINFO in your original script
# so I left it out
comment="$minutes_diff min Restart Downtime"

# The -d @- <<-JSON uses a heredoc so I can
# more nicely express the JSON you send

curl $url -1 \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $username $password" \
    -w "%{http_code}\n" \
    -d @- <<-JSON
{
    "start_time": "$start_time",
    "end_time": "$end_time",
    "comment": "$comment",
    "host_name": "$hostname",
    "downtime_type": "host"
}
JSON
```